# Express Checkout Digital Goods : Proxy Error on sandbox.paypal.com/incontext

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I have a Flash website. When I want to use Paypal Express Checkout with Digital Goods, I call this javascript code :

```
dg = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow();
dg.startFlow("http://mydomain.com/setup.php");
```

setup.php calls SetExpressCheckoutPayment function and redirect to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/incontext?token=...&useraction=commit

With Firebug I can see this address returns a 302, and redirects to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/checkout/webflow/sparta/expresscheckoutvalidatedataflow?exp_type=&cookiesBlocked=&token=...&useraction=commit
This adress returns also a 302 and redirects to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/checkout/webflow/sparta/expresscheckoutvalidatedataflow?execution=e1s1

Here it hangs for several minutes and ends with this error message :

```
Proxy Error
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /webapps/checkout/webflow/sparta/expresscheckoutvalidatedataflow.
Reason: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server
```

I started to get this error sometimes last week, and I have it every time today.
It happens on my MAMP environment and on my website.
I don't have SSL certificate but I didn't last week and it was not a problem.

Do you know anything about this error message ?

**Edit**

I tried with Opera, proxyError comes at a different step : https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/checkout/webflow/sparta/expresscheckoutvalidatedataflow?execution=e1s4

And once this morning on Firefox I had another Proxy Error after the first redirection :

```
Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /webapps/checkout/webflow/sparta/expresscheckoutvalidatedataflow.
Reason: Error reading from remote server
```

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that I have just started receiving this same issue in the past week. I've been in contact with a couple of their integration engineers today. I'll follow up with any luck if they come through.. It appears they have upgraded their platform recently, and I'm assuming they have some integration issues on their hands. I don't think the issue is your code, so don't scrap everything yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the Proxy Error anymore since yesterday. I didn't change anything so it seems PayPal servers are unstable...

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue since Sunday evening (sorry that I can't post this as a comment, don't have enough reputation yet).

I'm on LiquidWeb shared hosting, using the Merchant SDK ( https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php ).  I was on merchant-sdk-php-2.1.96 when the errors began, and tried upgrading to merchant-sdk-php-2.2.98 but now it is worse (won't even do the first redirect, which is confusing).  My code is server side, but getting the timeout and proxy error at the same urls:

```
            $setECResponse = $PayPal_service->SetExpressCheckout($setECReq);

            if($setECResponse->Ack == 'Success') {          
                $token = $setECResponse->Token;
                $payPalURL = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/incontext?token=' . $token;
                $this->Redirect($payPalURL);
            }
```

Comment: I rolled back my code since new code wasn't getting me anywhere, and now my error is different, at the first url:  ( https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/incontext?token=... ) I get: 

"Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /webapps/checkout/webflow/sparta/expresscheckoutincontextinitflow.

Reason: Error reading from remote server"

Comment: They just recently ported over to a new platform for development it looks like. I think they've got some bugs on their hands, im having the same issue. I'd bring your code back up to date, as i highly doubt it's you.